# Block property with parameters and setter

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a block with setter:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^action)(UIControlEvents);

- (void)setAction:(void (^)(UIControlEvents))action {
    // ?
}
```

I have to use setter and there is no option to skip it.
How can I access UIControlEvents parameter..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your block property by filling out your setter like this:

```
- (void)setAction:(void (^)(UIControlEvents))action {
    _action = action;
}
```

However, you won't be able to access any particular `UIControlEvents` parameter as you requested because you're the one providing it.  The `action` block takes the `UIControlEvents` value as an argument, so it won't be there within the block. Calling the action block with your `UIControlEvents` parameter might look something like this:

```
- (void)handleControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)events {
    if (self.action) self.action(events)
}
```